# Convert python pandas dataframe to array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I had a problem when I was making a dataset

I want to reshape pandas dataframe as a array as below.

If I made a pandas df like this,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
a = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'cc', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb']
b = ['123E2', 'BD23', '4124', '1535', 'A535', 'CCD35', '34EF3']
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': a, 'B': b}, index=index)
df

Output
    A   B
1   aa  123E2
2   bb  BD23
3   cc  4124
4   cc  1535
5   aa  A535
6   aa  CCD35
7   bb  34EF3

df1 = df.sort_values(by='A')
df1

Output
    A   B
1   aa  123E2
5   aa  A535
6   aa  CCD35
2   bb  BD23
7   bb  34EF3
3   cc  4124
4   cc  1535
```

Suppose 'A' means a person who takes a class, and 'B' means a class

I want to make it like that (reshape)

How can I do that ??

```
1   aa  [123E2, A535, CCD35]
2   bb  [BD23, 34EF3]
3   cc  [4124, 1535]
```

Thanks !

Comment: Yeeeesssss Thanks!!! :)

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Do you want to convert your DataFrame into np.ndarray or you just want to operate your DataFrame so that it looks like the way you want (the output is still a DataFrame)?

Comment: @nngeek I just want to reshape original data no matter it is a DataFrame or np.darray Thanks !